# Stream audio record from android device toanother

Tags: android, audio, stream, android-audiorecord

I want to make stream voice between microphone of android device to speaker of another, so I used Audiorecord !!

The activity that sends voice is :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

AudioRecord recorder;

private int sampleRate = 44100;
int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
private boolean status = true;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    startButton.setOnClickListener (startListener);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener (stopListener);

    minBufSize += 4096;
    System.out.println("minBufSize: " + minBufSize);
}

private final OnClickListener stopListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                status = false;
                recorder.release();
    }

};

private final OnClickListener startListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                status = true;
               try {

                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                Log.d("VS", "Socket Created");

                byte[] buffer = new byte[minBufSize];

                Log.d("VS","Buffer created of size " + minBufSize);
                DatagramPacket packet;

                final InetAddress destination = InetAddress.getByName("addresse");
                Log.d("VS", "Address retrieved");


                recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,minBufSize*10);
                Log.d("VS", "Recorder initialized");

                recorder.startRecording();


                while(status == true) {


                    //reading data from MIC into buffer
                    minBufSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                    //putting buffer in the packet
                    packet = new DatagramPacket (buffer,buffer.length,destination,port);

                    socket.send(packet);
                    System.out.println("MinBufferSize: " +minBufSize);
                   }



            } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
                Log.e("VS", "UnknownHostException");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("VS", "IOException");
            }            
    }

};


 }
```

and the activity in the android revice is :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static DatagramSocket socket;
private AudioTrack speaker;



private boolean status = true;


@SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.receive_button);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            status = true;
            try {

                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port);


                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];


                //minimum buffer size. need to be careful. might cause problems. try setting manually if any problems faced
                int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);

                speaker = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,minBufSize,AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

                speaker.play();

                while(status == true) {

                        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
                        socket.receive(packet);
                        Log.d("VR", "Packet Received");

                        buffer=packet.getData();
                        Log.d("VR", "Packet data read into buffer");

                        speaker.write(buffer, 0, minBufSize);
                        Log.d("VR", "Writing buffer content to speaker");


                }



            } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
                Log.e("VS", "UnknownHostException");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("VS", "IOException");
            }
        }
    });

    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.receive_button);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            status = false;
            speaker.release();

        }
    });
}
```

}

the sender works but when I click the button in the receiver app, that makes error : NULL POINTER EXCEPTION!!
How can I resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you get an exception you should add the exact stack trace that you're getting to your question, and also point out which lines in your code the line numbers in the stack trace correspond to.

Comment: How can you expect us to help you without the stack trace or, at least, the line that causes your exception?